# R-Tree Index stored in HBase Table - Is it viable?

Tags: indexing, mapreduce, hbase, r-tree

So I have been reading a lot about indexes, local, global, distributed, HDFS based, spatialhadoop stuff and I was wondering if it is viable time wise to store the R-tree index created from an input dataset in an HBase table? So you have a dataset you partition it based on some criteria and then while you make the R-Tree (leaves, branches etc.) you store them in the table. Does this make the index slower than searching with MapReduce in the local index files?

Answer (score 0):

Anything that may require non-local access, reading of additional memory, additional decoding, encoding and reencoding of data, additional boxing and unboxing and any kind of additional system or library calls will be slower. The question is how much - you'll need to experiment with that.